# angular expression in html view rendering same data for different expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, controller

Angular expressions on one of my view are rendering same data on screen

it would show : hello - hello ( for different expressions {{a}}, {{b}} )

There is cleary different data binded to 'a' and 'b' variables in controller.

**html view :**

```
    {{ a | json }} - {{ b | json }}
```

**angular controller:**

```
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, myservice) {

      var self = this;

      self.getA = function() {
        $scope.a = 'hello';
      }

      self.getB = function() {
        $scope.b = 'hey';
      }

      self.getA(); //call on controller startup
      self.getB();

    });
```

Comment: it should work fine please check [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rjpyEbPvgoQ2Ic1IrTQz?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works without any issue,

Make sure you are doing the following.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myctrl',[]);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
      var self = this;
      self.getA = function() {
        $scope.a = 'hello';
      }
      self.getB = function() {
        $scope.b = 'hey';
      }
      self.getA(); //call on controller startup
      self.getB();

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Dashboard</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<div ng-app="myctrl" >
<div ng-controller="myctrl as ctrl" >
 {{ a }} - {{ b }}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should the controller be registered as a a separate module for sure ?  currently its                        var app = angualr.module("app", []) and then app.controller('ctrl', function(1, 2) {}

Comment: its not registered separately

Comment: sorry figured , that 'myctrl'  module is ng-app